# AWK convert big unsigned int to signed int (binary)

Tags: bash, awk, type-conversion

in AWK i've got in one of fields some big values, like 3758096383 (in hex : DFFFFFFF). I want to convert this value into signed int (in this example -536870913, in hex same value DFFFFFFF). Is there some simple way for do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the logic, but something similar to this should do

```
awk '$1>=2^31{$1-=2^32}1'
```