# Awk command to convert hex to signed decimal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, text-editor

I have a text file which consists of 3 columns with hex numbers (values are variable, these used only as an example):

```
X     Y     Z
0a0a  0b0b  0c0c
0a0a  0b0b  0c0c
0a0a  0b0b  0c0c
0a0a  0b0b  0c0c
```

I want to convert these numbers to signed decimal and print them in the same structure they are in, so I did:

```
awk '{x="0x"$1;
      y="0x"$2;
      z="0x"$3;
      printf ("%d %d %d" x,y,z);}' input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

The list that I get as an output consists only of unsigned values.

Comment: Since the hex numbers in your sample input all start with a zero byte, they would normally be considered positive.  Should any of them be treated as negative?

Comment: can you post your expected output? and the awk snippet given has syntax issues

Comment: awk does not support it, try to use a hack like one described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551094/awk-convert-big-unsigned-int-to-signed-int-binary to prove awk inability use int2hex awk '{printf "%x/n" , -1}' it will tell you ffffffffffffffff try backward awk '{printf "%d/n, 0xffffffffffffffff"}' you will get a huge positive integer. It will be the same with shell printf command.

Comment: expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `awk` function to make a `Conversion from Two's Complement`:

```
function hex2int( hexstr, nbits )
{
    max = 2 ^ nbits
    med = max / 2

    num = strtonum( "0x" hexstr )

    return ((num < med) ? num : ( (num > med) ? num - max  :  -med ))
}
```

`4bit` Conversion examples:

```
print hex2int( "7", 4 ) # +7
print hex2int( "2", 4 ) # +2
print hex2int( "1", 4 ) # +1
print hex2int( "0", 4 ) # 0
print hex2int( "f", 4 ) # -1
print hex2int( "d", 4 ) # -3
print hex2int( "9", 4 ) # -7
print hex2int( "8", 4 ) # -8
```

`8bit` Conversion examples:

```
print hex2int( "7f", 8 ) # +127
print hex2int( "40", 8 ) # +64
print hex2int( "01", 8 ) # +1
print hex2int( "00", 8 ) # 0
print hex2int( "ff", 8 ) # -1
print hex2int( "40", 8 ) # -64
print hex2int( "81", 8 ) # -127
print hex2int( "80", 8 ) # -128
```

Putting all together using a `16bit` conversion:

```
#!/bin/awk

function hex2int( hex )
{
    num = strtonum( "0x" hex )

    return ((num < med) ? num : ( (num > med) ? num - max  :  -med ))
}

BEGIN {
    nbits = 16
    max = 2 ^ nbits
    med = max / 2
}

{
    for( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )
    {
        if( NR == 1 )
        {
            printf "%s%s", $i, OFS
        }
        else
        {
            printf "%d%s", hex2int($i), OFS
        }
    }

    printf "%s", ORS
}

# eof #
```

Input file:

```
X     Y     Z
0a0a  0b0b  0c0c
abcd  ef01  1234
ffff  fafa  baba
12ab  abca  4321
```

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk -- input.txt
```

Output:

```
X Y Z 
2570 2827 3084 
-21555 -4351 4660 
-1 -1286 -17734 
4779 -21558 17185
```

**Reference:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Hope it helps!

Comment: Would `return (num < med) ? num : num - max)` work as a simpler alternative?